# Communicate with a page script from a content script in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, scope

I'm loading a content script (`1.js`), which at some point appends a `<script>`-element, that point to a file inside the extension (`2.js`). `2.js` can't be included as a content script.

Is there a way to use a variable defined inside `2.js` from `1.js`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) between your background page and content script.  The background page holds the value (either by loading `2.js` as a script, or by having `2.js` be the application's background script itself) and listen for incoming messages with `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener`.  The content script sends a request, and the content script sends a response with the desired value.

Comment: The variable is an object. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: I believe message passing works for objects that don't have cyclic references.  If your object has cyclic references, that makes thing a lot harder, since they can't be stringified -- you might just need to strip them out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. A bit dirty, but works with a dynamic object, which I had in question.

I simply added all the code by injecting it to the page. Here's my content script:

```
var path = document.createElement('div');
path.id = 'codearea-path';
path.innerHTML = chrome.extension.getURL('/');
path.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(path);

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL('1.js');
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Then I used the same kind of code to include `2.js` inside `1.js`.

Comment: Sure, that works -- I assumed that type of behavior was out-of-bounds, though, since you said `2.js` couldn't be used a content script (but I think I understand now that you mean that it shouldn't be loaded every time at load time -- dynamic injection is okay, yes?).  I believe you could also use `chrome.tabs.executeScript('2.js')` from your background page.

Comment: You're right, pardon me for any confusion. I will also consider using `executeScript()`, but at the moment the extension doesn't need a background page.